# US pronunciation of short vowels as long

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I'm an Australian and have been watching a lot of soccer via US Fox Sports.

I've noticed the US presenters pronounce a lot of words using a long vowel sound where I would use a short vowel.

For example,

- The *mi* in semi-final: I say it like *me*, whereas they say it like *my*
- The *pen* in penalised: I say it like *pen*, they say it like *peen*

Edit: I think I misremembered penalised as penalty

Some questions:

1. Is this common across the US?
2. Is the difference applied uniformly? (i.e. are there any rules to it)
3. Is it a recent variation in pronunciation?
4. When and where can the difference be traced to?

Comment: "sem-*eye*" is certainly common across the US. They also tend to say "*dee*-fence" rather than "deaf-*ence*". (Italics used to show stress.)

Comment: Never heard a US native speaker say PEEN-alty

Comment: As @sumelic notes, the variant pronunciation of 'semi' is peculiar to that word. I don't think that is a general sound change of /i:/ to /ai/. Can you think of other words with a similar change? Also for pen to peen (/e/ to /i:/), any other examples?

Comment: I’ve updated question - I think I meant to say penalised

Comment: @AndyT Defense as 'dee-fence' is generally only in the context of sports

Comment: @Unrelated: or more generally, when it stands in contrast to "offense", either implicitly or explicitly, as in the proverb "The best defense is a good offense."

Comment: I'm a New Yorker (sometimes I like to write it "Ñawka", since that's how a lot of them pronounce it), and around here, I hear both "se-mee" and "se-my". It seems to depend on both who's saying it, and how emphasized the word is in what they're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "long e" and "short e" in *penalize*

The variability between "short e" (IPA: /ɛ/) and "long e" (IPA: /i/ or /iː/)  in words like *penalize* can be attributed to a conflict between the use of "long e" in the related word *penal,* and a certain tendency to use "short e" in a stressed syllable that is followed by more than one other syllable in the same word. (There is likewise a tendency to pronounce the letter "a" as "short a", "o" as "short o", and "i" as "short i" in the same conditions.)

The tendency to pronounce the letter "e" as "short e" in contexts like this is not particularly strong, and has many exceptions. Some of these exceptions can be categorized into classes (e.g. certain affixes, like *-ly* or *-ness,* add a syllable but never cause vowel shortening, so we have a "long e" sound in words like *l**e**gally* and ***e**venness*) but other exceptions appear fairly arbitrary (we have a "long e" sound in *ob**e**sity,* as in the related adjective *ob**e**se,* but a "short e" in *ser**e**nity,* unlike in the related adjective *ser**e**ne*).

Most verbs ending in the suffix *-ize* use the same vowel length as the related unsuffixed word (examples: *l**e**galize* and *d**e**monize,* with "long e" as in *l**e**gal* and *d**e**mon*) but for whatever reason, *p**e**nalize* doesn't necessarily have the long vowel of *p**e**nal.* Possibly there has been some influence from the pronunciation of the word *p**e**nalty,* which as far as I know is pronounced with "short e" by all or almost all speakers.

I don't actually know how frequent each pronunciation of *penalize/penalise* is in different regions, but there are certainly some US speakers who say "PEN-alize"<sup>1</sup>, and some non-US speakers who say "PEE-nalize" (the Oxford English Dictionary gives the pronunciation as "Brit.  /ˈpiːnəlʌɪz/, /ˈpiːnl̩ʌɪz/,  U.S. /ˈpɛnlˌaɪz/, /ˈpinlˌaɪz/").

### variation between dialects in the use of "long" and "short" vowels in other words

A somewhat similar example may be the pronunciation of the word *[privacy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399867/pronunciation-of-priv-in-british-english-and-american-english),* which has a "long i" sound for most American English speakers, but a "short i" sound for many British English speakers (I don't know which pronunciation of *privacy* is more common in Australian English).

I don't see any connection between the two pronunciations that you mentioned. There is a previous question about the pronunciation of *semi-*: [pronunciation US-UK in words like “semi”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113745). *Multi-* and *anti-* are two other "prefixes" that show similar variation between /aɪ/ and /ɪ/ or /i/, with the /aɪ/ variants apparently more common in American English.

---

1. Some American speakers might say something like "PIN-alize" and also pronounce *pen* as "pin". A merger between the "short e" and "short i" sounds before a nasal consonant (/n/, /m/ or /ŋ/) is known to be a feature of accents in the Southern United States.

Comment: I think I must have mis-remembered penalty for penalised. Thanks!